# Ace selects all text in editor on focus in Firefox

Tags: firefox, ace-editor

I have an Ace editor embedded into a Bootstrap 3 modal. Before the modal is shown, I set the value in the editor like this:

```
var editor = ace.edit(aceEditorId);
editor.session.setValue(val, -1); // set value at document start
editor.session.selection.clearSelection();
```

I also have a "shown" event handler for the modal to resize the editor:

```
$(editSnippetSelector).on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
        var editorId = getSnippetEditorId();
        var snippetEditor = ace.edit(editorId);
        snippetEditor.resize();
```

When I focus on the editor in Firefox, all of the editor text gets selected. I can't move the cursor or remove the selection by clicking. I can only erase the text by pressing backspace or another key (for example a letter or enter).

This doesn't happen in Chrome or IE.

As an experiment, I also added this code to no avail:

```
codeEditor.on("focus", function () {
    codeEditor.getSession().setValue(codeEditor.getSession().getValue());
    codeEditor.clearSelection();
});
```

Where else should I look? Has anyone else seen similar behavior?

**UPDATE:**

I noticed that there is an `onSelect` function in `ace.js` that gets called in an infinite loop. It's on line 2061: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace-builds/blob/master/src-noconflict/ace.js#L2061

Here is the code of the function:

```
var onSelect = function(e) {
    if (copied) {
        copied = false;
    } else if (isAllSelected(text)) {
        host.selectAll();
        resetSelection();
    } else if (inputHandler) {
        resetSelection(host.selection.isEmpty());
    }
};
```

Walking through the code in Firefox's debugger shows that the call to `isAllSelected(text)` returns true and so the selection event is raised again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ace.js` has an `onSelect` handler which gets called in an infinite loop in Firefox.

Here is the original code of that function:

```
var onSelect = function(e) {
    if (copied) {
        copied = false;
    } else if (isAllSelected(text)) {
        host.selectAll();
        resetSelection();
    } else if (inputHandler) {
        resetSelection(host.selection.isEmpty());
    }
};
```

`text` is a textarea DOM element. `isAllSelected(text)` checks if all of the text is selected using this code:

```
    return text.selectionStart === 0 && text.selectionEnd === text.value.length;
```

As you can see this returns true even for an empty text area, which then causes `host.selectAll()` to be called which somehow propagates back down and fires the select event again.

I added a check for empty textarea and it fixed the problem. The code is now like this:

```
var onSelect = function(e) {
    if (copied) {
        copied = false;
    } else if (text.value && isAllSelected(text)) {
        host.selectAll();
        resetSelection();
    } else if (inputHandler) {
        resetSelection(host.selection.isEmpty());
    }
};
```

Comment: To update this in the minified ace.js, find the first occurrence of `E(n)` (case sensitive) and replace it with `n.value&&E(n)`. (Thank you very much for this answer.)

Comment: Shouldn't this fix already be added to the official ace.js code? This is 2017 and the bug is still present. Thanks for the answer DanielGabriel & @mch

Comment: Thanks for answer. Same problem appears when editor is in form and you call form.reset()

Comment: 2022 and this bug is still present in embedded editor.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is caused by out of date cached size in renderer.
You need to call `editor.resize()` after modal is shown

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't help. I updated my question with more code - I do call resize() when the modal is shown. By then the value is already set, and the problem still persists. I tried reversing (resize, then set the value) by putting this code in the "shown" event handler: `snippetEditor.resize(); snippetEditor.session.setValue(snippetEditor.session.getValue(), -1);` with the same result.

Comment: Could you create a jsbin demo for the issue, or put your page somewhere visible, i am not able to reproduce the issue with the code snippets from your question.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle but it doesn't reproduce the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/daniel_gabriel/02t1wphe/2/ I'm going to continue investigating.

Comment: Your jsfiddle didn't run because of script mime type issue. I've updated it to http://jsfiddle.net/02t1wphe/8/, but with that version i couldn't reproduce the issue on firefox

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this in jsfiddle, but I think something else is going on. I updated the question.

Comment: that function is used to detect selectAll from context menu, perhaps you have some other script on your page that triggers it?

Comment: That's very weird. I don't use, override, or set handlers for the context menu. Is there any other way this could be triggered?

Comment: Either way, the `onSelect` handler looks to be causing an infinite loop. If the text area is empty, it'll call `selectAll()` causing the whole cycle again. Doesn't that look like a bug in Ace?

Comment: Not sure, i think setSelectionRange shouldn't emit events. Do you have some code that calls select() on textarea which is being focused?

Comment: No, this text area belongs to Ace, so I don't set focus on it explicitly. The problem happens when I tab into Ace from another input. When the editor is not fully in the view, it jumps (scrolls into view?). Maybe something happens there. I will investigate more.